# NetLogo autocompletion with windows

Tags: netlogo

Anyone know how to use the autocompletion in NetLogo with a windows system. I saw something like this in a video, he was using mac. The document said version after 6.0 support autocompletion

to setup
  clear-all

It supposes to be autocomplete suggestion after I type clear

Answer (score 4):

Autocompletion is not triggered automatically: type the first letters of the command, than press CTRL + SPACE, and a dropdown menu will appear with command suggestions. Please check the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: Can I change CTRL+SPACE?